# If a quantum state occupied by an electron has a $m^*_e>0$, will the same state if unoccupied have $m_h^*<0$ and vice-versa?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, electronic-band-theory

For electrons in a periodic potential, the effective mass of an electron in an energy band can be positive or negative depending on its quantum state specified by $n,k$ i.e. its energy $E_n(k)$ and crystal momentum $\hbar k$ in the band or in short, where it lies in the band. This is because the effective mass is given by $$m^*=\frac{\hbar^2}{\Big(\frac{d^2E_n(k)}{dk^2}\Big)}$$ which changes from point to point.

If the same quantum state is unoccupied, we'll get a hole, with same quantum numbers. Can we say that the effective mass of the corresponding hole is negative? And when electron effective mass is negative, corresponding hole mass is positive?

My reasoning is like this. Since the hole moves opposite to the electron, and since the motion in presence of an electric field is semiclassically described by Newton's law $$F=-eE=m^*a,$$ the hole mass must be opposite to the electron mass. But if we assume hole has a positive charge $q=+e=-(-e)$, then there is a compensating negative sign, it will make effective mass of hole to be positive.

Comment: No, that isn’t right.

Comment: A *hole* has a negative effective mass. But a hole exists only where the energy states are saturated (i.e., the conduction band)..  An empty state in the valence band is not a hole.

Comment: @garyp but in an intrinsic semiconductor, an empty state in a valence band is called a hole. At any finite temperature, some of the electron from the valence band is thermally activated to the conduction band leaving holes in the valence band. What is wrong with this?

Comment: Ugh. In an episode of mental confusion, I swapped *valance* and *conduction*.   Sorry, folks.